# Почему не работает Drawable для ProgressBara?

Tags: java, android

Почему не работает Drawable для ProgressBara?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadius="45dp"
        android:thickness="10dp"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="#961aa1" />
    </shape>
</item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="10dp"
            android:innerRadius="45dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#00E277" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

А вот сам Progress

```
<ProgressBar
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="50"
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить `drawable` в `style`

```
<style name="MyProgressBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progress</item>
</style>
```

а здесь

```
 <ProgressBar
            style="@style/MyProgressBarStyle"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="50"
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: Не помогло. Я уверено проблема кроется в файле `custom_progress`.....